# How to create custom WebSecurity.Login and WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount methods in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, custom-membershipprovider

When we choose `New Project --> MVC 4 --> Internet Application`, it will automatically generate AccountController for us. In this controller, I only care about 2 actions, `Login` and `Register`.

In MVC 3, it uses Membership's static methods, `ValidateUser`in `Login` action and `CreateUser` in `Register`. So, if I want to integrate it with my own database, I just need create `CustomMembershipProvider` by extending `MembershipProvider` and override that two methods.

But in MVC 4, it uses `WebSecurity.Login` and `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount`. My questions are:

1. How can I make it use my own database like I did in MVC 3?
2. What's the different? Why doesn't it keep using static Membership methods? Why does it have to change to `WebSecurity`?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to implement you own Membership and Role providers.

Custom Provider:

```
namespace MyApp.Helpers
{
    public class CustomProviderProvider : SimpleMembershipProvider
    {
        public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            return base.GetUser(username, userIsOnline);
        }

        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return true; // base.ValidateUser(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

You will just need to override the methods you want to "intercept" (ie ValidateUser). You will also need to register the provider in the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
        <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="MyApp.Helpers.CustomMembershipProvider, MyApp" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

You should also have a Filter called "InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute"

```
namespace CustomPortal.Filters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<CustomPortalContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new CustomPortalContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }
//Here is where you give it your connection string name
                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("CustomPortal", "UserProfile", "UserId", "EmailAddress", autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why do I need that filter? Just for creating database? So if I use Entity Framework, I don't need this filter?

Comment: How about create custom SimpleRoleProvider and config it?

Comment: The filter doesn't just create the database, It also initializes the WebSecurity class. By doing this you are able to tell WebSecurity which database and fields to use. The filter is just a good place to the initialization because the attributes are reusable. You could do the initialization in the gloabal.asax page i'm sure. However, that's not as granular if you need more control and initializing in other places may lead to duplicated code, which can turn into a maintenance nightmare. Also, even if you use entity framework you would still use something to this effect.

Comment: Actually, if you weren't using EF this would be a little more complex.

Comment: @Forte_201092 did I answer your question or are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: I'm using VS 2013, created the Default MVC 4 selected Internet Application as the authentication and the Filter is already there. So would i still need to amend the filter class and web.config?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC 4 uses a new membership provider called SimpleMembershipProvider.  WebMatrix is a facade over SimpleMembershipProvider.  There is no longer a need to modify the config file with ASP.NET MVC 4.  More info here: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2013/02/aspnet-mvc-4-membership-users-passwords.html

1.How can I make it use my own database like I did in MVC 3?

A: No need to override SimpleMembershipProvider if you want to roll your own.  Remove the reference to the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` in the `AccountController` class and modify the methods in the `AccountController` class.

2.What's the different? Why doesn't it keep using static Membership methods? Why does it have to change to WebSecurity?

A: ASP.NET MVC 4 Now uses a new membership provider: SimpleMembershipProvider.